# ASP.NET - Checking if request is authenticated in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

In my master page's Page_Load event, I have the following code:

```
if(!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
} else 
{
   // Do something. Note: Any work here gets performed when request is authenticated.
}
```

However, when I load a content page (which uses the master) while not authenticated, I do not get redirected to the login page. To get the desired behavior, I also need to add the above check in the Page_Load event in my content page.

Not a huge issue but is just annoying having the above check in every content page.

So I am curious, what is the reason for the master page not redirecting to login page when request isn't authenticated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.net Masterpage\_load first or page\_load first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470196/asp-net-masterpage-load-first-or-page-load-first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is FormsAuthentication to redirect to login page, when user has not logged in why don't you use config file to do this?

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This should automatically send all 'anonymous' users to the configured login page for FormAuth.

Comment: That, my friend, is very helpful :) the original question still stands though.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm also unable to figure out why that code doesn't work for you. I dont think its the order of the Load event, no matter which goes first, redirection should work. I think examples you have given are not sufficient to figure this out.

Comment: This is a classic unhelpful SO answer-- technically correct, but not addressing the actual question! Setting this in web.config is global. A single site can have multiple Master pages, so objectively this isn't the answer to what is being asked here. See @Sagar's answer for the actual solution

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried debugging this - is your masterpage's Page_Load definitely running?
You might have an AutoEventWireUp set to false or similar...

Comment: My masterpage's Page_Load is definitely running, yes. Anything I do in the "else" block gets executed. So does any code outside the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to see the [life cycle of Master page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/0db883da-82de-4d13-9b0f-c7aa19d0f022); through this you can understand how it all works.

First the individual `.aspx` page's `Page_Load()` method is run and then, after execution of that method finishes, the master page's `Page_Load()` method is run.

Related question:[What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET WebForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597042/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-webform)

Answer (score 1):

When you need the same functionality in several places, you can use [ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Put your code in the `usercontrol` and add the usercontrol to the pages where you need this code to be executed

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why your code doesn't work, it work perfect with me.
You can check in your web.config, are you implement the url of login page

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/somepage.aspx" />
    </authentication>
```